# Making an equalizer for mp3 player

Tags: c#, multimedia, equalizer

I want to make an equalizer for the mp3 player I made, but I don't know which way is the easiest way to do it. I'm using mci in my player. Please help me!!! Thanks

Comment: If you are not more specific you won't get any useful answers. What it is exactly that you need? How to draw the equalizer? How to get the data for it? Something else?

Comment: Sorry, I want to get the data of the equalizer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018898/sound-with-equalizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ["Filters" section of musicdsp.org](http://www.musicdsp.org/archive.php?classid=3) should be an excellent place to get started. I've seen ports of the 3 band eq in a couple of different places.