# Sound with equalizer

Tags: c#, audio, equalizer, cscore

I am trying to create an equalizer using C#.
Seen NAudio quite a lot; however I could not find any working equalizer to work with NAudio.
Considering I'm a little bit lost; I came here to ask a way to create or implement an equalizer in C#.

Note: I've tried out the System.Media.SoundPlayer; but that SoundPlayer does not even support anything that has to do with DSP.
How can I Implement an Equalizer and/or is there any audio library that works with "pure" audio outside?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So is there another audio library which works with "pure" audio outside?

Yes there is one: https://cscore.codeplex.com

According to the [EqualizerSample](http://cscore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Equalizer/MainWindow.cs), you can use the equalizer like that:

```
using CSCore;
using CSCore.Codecs;
using CSCore.SoundOut;
using CSCore.Streams;
using System;
using System.Threading;

...

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string filename = @"C:\Temp\test.mp3";
    EventWaitHandle waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    try
    {
        //create a source which provides audio data
        using(var source = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(filename))
        {
            //create the equalizer.
            //You can create a custom eq with any bands you want, or you can just use the default 10 band eq.
            Equalizer equalizer = Equalizer.Create10BandEqualizer(source);

            //create a soundout to play the source
            ISoundOut soundOut;
            if(WasapiOut.IsSupportedOnCurrentPlatform)
            {
                soundOut = new WasapiOut();
            }
            else
            {
                soundOut = new DirectSoundOut();
            }

            soundOut.Stopped += (s, e) => waitHandle.Set();

            IWaveSource finalSource = equalizer.ToWaveSource(16); //since the equalizer is a samplesource, you have to convert it to a raw wavesource
            soundOut.Initialize(finalSource); //initialize the soundOut with the previously created finalSource
            soundOut.Play();

            /*
             * You can change the filter configuration of the equalizer at any time.
             */
            equalizer.SampleFilters[0].SetGain(20); //eq set the gain of the first filter to 20dB (if needed, you can set the gain value for each channel of the source individually)

            //wait until the playback finished
            //of course that is optional
            waitHandle.WaitOne();

            //remember to dispose and the soundout and the source
            soundOut.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch(NotSupportedException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fileformat not supported: " + ex.Message);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

You can configure the equalizer to what ever you want. And since it runs 100% in realtime, all changes are getting applied instantly. If needed, there is also a possiblity to access modify each channel separately.

Comment: Hi! today i updated the CSCORE, it solved a problem but made another problem! now the problem is using equalizer is not the same as before(this   code) and i could not figure out how to  use it. could you help me please?